# NSStream connection to server issues with data being sent

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, network-programming, nsstream

I am trying to communicate with a java server using NSStream however I can't determine how to limit the data sent by this code to a single "hello" and also prevent it from lopping off the initial 2 characters.

```
NSInputStream *inputStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream;

-(void)initNetworkCommunication {
    NSLog(@"init net con");
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", 6066, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}

-(void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
switch(eventCode) {
    case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: {
        if (stream == outputStream) {
            NSString *res = @"<Hello>";
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[res dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `write:maxLength:` on the outside of the delegate method `stream:handleEvent:`.

Comment: wrote a simple method to write to the stream and i do not receive a result